# Errors: FUNCTION EMP_SAL_RANKING

Tags: oracle, plsql

i dont know why this function is not working ,i actually want to make a function which calculate the salary ranking of the employee based on the current minimum and maximum salaries for employees in the same job category

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION emp_sal_ranking 

(empid NUMBER)

 RETURN NUMBER IS 

 minsal emp.sal%type;


 maxsal emp.sal%type;

 v_jobid emp.job%type;

 v_sal emp.sal%type;

BEGIN

 select job,sal,INTO v_jobid,V_sal from emp 

WHERE empno = empid;

 select MIN(sal),MAX(sal) INTO minsal,maxsal 

from emp

   where job=V_jobid;

   return ((V_sal - minsal)/(maxsal-minsal));

 END emp_sal_ranking;
```

Comment: You have a very uncommon definition of "ranking". As written, after you fix the syntax errors, the result for a given employee will depend only on his salary, and on the min and the max salaries for his job; but it will not depend on how many other employees with the same job have a higher salary then him, or how many have a lower salary. So what kind of "**rank**" is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not working" is difficult to debug. What does it mean?

If it is yet another of your typos (really, you should pay more attention to what you're doing), then remove superfluous comma. After that, function returns result. I don't know whether it is what you wanted or not, but - it "works".

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_sal_ranking(
  2    empid NUMBER
  3  )RETURN NUMBER IS
  4
  5    minsal   emp.sal%TYPE;
  6    maxsal   emp.sal%TYPE;
  7    v_jobid  emp.job%TYPE;
  8    v_sal    emp.sal%TYPE;
  9  BEGIN
 10    SELECT job,
 11           sal                  --> remove comma
 12           into v_jobid,
 13           v_sal
 14    FROM emp
 15    WHERE empno = empid;
 16
 17    SELECT MIN(sal),
 18           MAX(sal)
 19    INTO
 20      minsal,
 21      maxsal
 22    FROM emp
 23    WHERE job = v_jobid;
 24
 25    return((v_sal - minsal)/(maxsal - minsal));
 26  END emp_sal_ranking;
 27  /

Function created.

SQL> select emp_sal_ranking(7499) from dual;

EMP_SAL_RANKING(7499)
---------------------
                    1

SQL>
```